# Integrating Smack 4.1 in android

Tags: android, chat, openfire, smack

I have gone through smack 4.1 documentation as given https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/tree/master/documentation . But I'm not getting connected when try to connect to openfire server. Can anyone give me a working code. My openfire configuration is working. I have checked it using  mac IM client.

Comment: link https://github.com/fangzhen/androidxmppclient

Comment: thanks @ask4solutions. Even though I wanted just the code fragment for connection this is much more than that. thank you for your great help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue when I tried exactly as in documentation.
But I found some changes needed after a research. Here is the code that I've used.

```
public void connect() throws IOException, XMPPException, SmackException {
    XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();

    config.setUsernameAndPassword("username","password");
    config.setServiceName(Config.XMPP_DOMAIN);
    config.setHost(Config.XMPP_HOST);
    config.setPort(Config.XMPP_PORT);

    mConnection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config.build());

    try {
        mConnection.connect();
        mConnection.login();

    } catch (SmackException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //ChatManager.getInstanceFor(mConnection).addChatListener(this);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

check out the link working example http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000119

Comment: I want to implement smack 4.1. not asmack since it is obsolete. thanks